# Converting string to an integer between a particular range

Tags: php, integer

I have alphanumeric string values. I need to represent each string with an integer value.

Resultant integers must be between 30 and 150.
Multiple strings can have same integer value.
A specific string must give the same integer value in every run.
Crypto is not important, string values are not valuable.
Faster calculation is preferred.
All integer musn't have the same value.

Edit: I tried `intval()`, but it gave me zero. Then I tried `md5` and `sha1` which gave me long strings. I tried `base_convert` but couldn't make it.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, please?

Comment: This is called "hashing", google it.

Comment: the way you state your problem, representing every string by the number of 42 would meet your specs.

Comment: I tried hashing like this: base_convert(hash("md4",$string), 16, 10)

Comment: Of course I googled it. I asked it after couldn't find a proper way.

Comment: What *purpose* do you wan't to use the hash for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would require a hash function. Your range is `150-30=120` so you'll need to modulo 120 (`% 120`) the result and add 30.

In PHP most standard hash functions (md5, sha) are for security purposes and return a string those aren't very useful. In this case you could use a Cyclic Redundancy Check: http://php.net/crc32. This isn't a hash (values aren't distributed evenly) but probably close enough for your purposes.

```
$stringhash = crc32($string) % 120 + 30;
```

If you need a more even distribution you can also user a simple standard hash, e.g. md5, but this is slower.

```
// Take the first 8 alphanumeric digits of the hash (= 32 bits) because we want to keep an int and not convert it to a floating point
$stringhash = intval(substr(md5($string), 0, 8), 16) % 120 + 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using @dtech's answer I finalized my function like this:

```
public function convertStringToInteger($string, $min, $max, $dateDepended=FALSE) {
    $interval = $max-$min;
    if ($dateDepended) {
        $addMore=strtotime("today");
    } else {
        $addMore=0;
    }
    return ( (crc32($string)+$addMore) % $interval ) + $min;
}

convertStringToInteger("myword",30,150,TRUE);
```